# Send one email to each user with different content from database

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

So basically i have the following tables:

`users
id - email - username - password`

and

`todo
id - user_id - name - description - reminder - reminder_date`

I want to send an email to each user to notice them that they have some tasks to do when the reminder_date = 'today'. This will be handled by a cron job.
The problem is that i have managed to extract the users and i can easily just send an email to those users but i also want to send the "todo.name" in the email body so they can know what tasks are due for the day.

Until now i have the following:

`$users = DB::select()->from('todo')->join('users', 'INNER')->on('todo.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('todo.reminder', '=', 1)->and_where('reminder_date', '=', Date::formatted_time('now', 'Y-m-d'))->and_where('todo.status', '=', 'active')
            ->execute()
            ->as_array();`

and with the following:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
            $count++;
            $allemails[] = $v['email'];
            $mailsUnique = array_unique($allemails);
        }

        $max = sizeof($mailsUnique);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
            foreach ($users as $k) {
                if ($mailsUnique[$i] == $k['email']) {
                  $task[$mailsUnique[$i]][] = $k['task'];
                } else {
              }
            }
          }
```

With the following code, i have a multi array with each task for each email. I can't seem to figure it out how to send one email to each user with every "task name" which corresponds to that user as mail body.

For example:

```
array(2) (
    "someEmail.yyy@provider.com" => array(1) (
        0 => string(6) "Do something"         <--- Task Name
        1 => string(6) "Do something else"    <--- Task Name
    )
    "otherEmail@provider.com" => array(1) (
        0 => string(6) "aaaaaa"               <--- Task Name
    )
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the outer array with a `key => value` loop to pull the emails address. It would look something like this:

```
foreach ( $array as $email => $tasks ) {
    foreach ( $tasks as $task ) {
        // send email to $email for each task or put together the list of tasks to put into one email below this loop.
    }
}
```